# How do I go about preventing the print statement from running until the loop has finished with the quiz/score inputs?

Tags: python-3.x

Keeps printing for every time it runs though the loop

```
quizzes_taking = int(input('How many quizzes is the student taking?'))
total_score = 0.0
for quiz in range(quizzes_taking):
    score = int(input(f'Enter the score of quiz #{quiz+1}: '))
    total_score = total_score + score
    average = total_score / quizzes_taking
    print(f'Your Quiz average is: {average:<.2f}. ')
```

Comment: You need to take operations that you only need to perform once out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
quizzes_taking = int(input('How many quizzes is the student taking?'))
total_score = 0.0
for quiz in range(quizzes_taking):
    score = int(input(f'Enter the score of quiz #{quiz+1}: '))
    total_score = total_score + score
    average = total_score / quizzes_taking
print('Your Quiz average is: {<.2f} .'.format(average))
```